# map throw array of objects to calc the vlaue of a specific object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

Hey i need to map throw this array and get the calc of all worth value comabine of all the products with immediate = 0,  how could i done it right?

i try some stuff by i cant get how to do it right, thanks for the blessed helper!

```
let items = [
  {
    name: 'קרן השתלמות',
    currency: 'ILS',
    geo: undefined,
    worth: 150000,
    portfolioPer: 0.273,
    predictedYield: 3,
    annualExpenses: NaN,
    expectedRevenue: NaN,
    appreciation: NaN,
    managementFee: 2,
    immediate: 0,
    yield: 1500,
    yieldPer: 0.01,
    totalYieldPer: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'קרן השתלמות',
    currency: 'ILS',
    geo: undefined,
    worth: 160000,
    portfolioPer: 0.291,
    predictedYield: 5,
    annualExpenses: NaN,
    expectedRevenue: NaN,
    appreciation: NaN,
    managementFee: 1,
    immediate: 1,
    yield: 6400,
    yieldPer: 0.04,
    totalYieldPer: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'קרן השתלמות של עומרי',
    currency: 'ILS',
    geo: undefined,
    worth: 240000,
    portfolioPer: 0.436,
    predictedYield: 3,
    annualExpenses: NaN,
    expectedRevenue: NaN,
    appreciation: NaN,
    managementFee: 1.5,
    immediate: 0,
    yield: 3600,
    yieldPer: 0.015,
    totalYieldPer: 0
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let items = [
  {
    name: 'קרן השתלמות',
    currency: 'ILS',
    geo: undefined,
    worth: 150000,
    portfolioPer: 0.273,
    predictedYield: 3,
    annualExpenses: NaN,
    expectedRevenue: NaN,
    appreciation: NaN,
    managementFee: 2,
    immediate: 0,
    yield: 1500,
    yieldPer: 0.01,
    totalYieldPer: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'קרן השתלמות',
    currency: 'ILS',
    geo: undefined,
    worth: 160000,
    portfolioPer: 0.291,
    predictedYield: 5,
    annualExpenses: NaN,
    expectedRevenue: NaN,
    appreciation: NaN,
    managementFee: 1,
    immediate: 1,
    yield: 6400,
    yieldPer: 0.04,
    totalYieldPer: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'קרן השתלמות של עומרי',
    currency: 'ILS',
    geo: undefined,
    worth: 240000,
    portfolioPer: 0.436,
    predictedYield: 3,
    annualExpenses: NaN,
    expectedRevenue: NaN,
    appreciation: NaN,
    managementFee: 1.5,
    immediate: 0,
    yield: 3600,
    yieldPer: 0.015,
    totalYieldPer: 0
  }
];

console.log(items.reduce((sum, element) => {
    if(element.immediate === 0) {
      sum += element.worth
    }
    return sum;
}, 0));
```